# Defining CSS in HTML div?

Tags: html, css

I know I can do this:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello!</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
```

but what if I am making JUST a div and I want to be able to style that div? (because I want to have the item itself, I don't want to touch the rest of that page)

I currently have:

```
<div class="hbrmenu">
  <a href="#" class="hbr-toggle-btn"></a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and I want to be able to style .hbrmenu in another file (a css)

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly (which I'm not sure I do) you could just use inline style `style=""` if you want this DIV self-contained.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you talking about the `style` attribute? Or using `<style>` tags in your html? but you said *"I want to be able to style .hbrmenu in another file (a css)"* so I'm assuming you want to use an external stylesheet with a `link` tag?

Comment: @MichaelCoker I am talking about I want to style it with:
.hbrmenu {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

Yes...

Comment: @Squallz then put that inbetween `<style></style>` tags in your HTML page, or put that in the external file "css/style.css" and use the `link` tag like you said you already know how to do.

Comment: do you mean that you include that div in your document via a script ? If yes where is the problem to set the css inside your actual stylesheet ? Clarify your question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have trouble expressing your question clearly. As far as I understand you want to have your hbrmenu to achieve another styling effects. If so, you don't need another css file. All you have to do is specify a **CSS MEDIA RULE**. For best results, create a html file then paste the code below so you can see the effect.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
    .class1{
     /*add properties*/
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
    body {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .class1{
     /*add properties*/
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
Background changes as you resize browser. 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I get this but what if I want this to show up on ONLY one page? Can I have html and head tags inside every individual file I want to have on the site?

Edit: For instance, on my XenForo forum, there is a list of "Templates" that I can edit. These will show up if I edit them and they are all individual files.

Comment: You can have multiple CCS on one html. Similarly, you can choose what CSS stylesheet you want to add.

Comment: And what if I am using xenforo? I want to add custom stuff to the front page of the site which issues an index obviously but I can't even find the file to edit.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to style `.hbrmenu` in another file (a css)

You already answered your own question, you create a CSS file and link it in the `head` just the way you did it, then you style the `div` something like this:

```css
.hbrmenu {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="hbrmenu">
  <a href="#" class="hbr-toggle-btn"></a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Note** if you are trying to do inline CSS either using `style` or inline attributes, keep it in mind that is a bad practice, so use an external file as mentioned above.

Comment: Hmm...I don't think you guys are quite understanding.

I don't want to use a <head> tag. I just want the file to have a div and that's it. If I add head and title and all that, it will change the main page and I simply want this to work as an "addon" on top of the page.

Comment: what?? what kind of page are you doing?

Comment: Editing Xenforo.

Comment: Just add the rule for `.hbrmenu` in your CSS file that you have to have somewhere in your head.

Comment: I already have my navbar, I am trying to make this as a hamburger menu that appears on mobile and lower resolution (when the window is smaller) which replaces the navbar

Comment: so? you can have all your rules in one CSS file